# Compiling Vigra with openEXR fails

Tags: vigra

I try to install Vigra with openEXR but no installation guide exist for that.
ps. Also I install Lemon library, and it is not found by vigra...

I tried....

```
sudo cmake -VIGRA_STATIC_LIB:BOOL=ON  -WITH_BOOST_GRAPH:BOOL=ON  -WITH_BOOST_THREAD:BOOL=ON  -WITH_HDF5:BOOL=ON -WITH_LEMON:BOOL=ON -WITH_OPENEXR:BOOL=ON ..
```

but without success...

```
-- Configuring VIGRA version 1.11.1
-- Checking template recursion depth: ok
-- Searching for ZLIB
--    in default locations
-- Searching for TIFF
--    in default locations
-- Searching for JPEG
--    in default locations
-- Searching for PNG
--    in default locations
-- Searching for FFTW3
--    in default locations
-- Searching for FFTW3F
--    in default locations
-- Searching for HDF5
--    in default locations
--    Checking HDF5 version (at least 1.8): ok
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Searching for Boost (at least version 1.40.0)
--    in default locations
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Checking for threading support:   std::thread
--     (added compiler flags: -pthread -std=c++11)
-- Detected C++ version: 201103
-- Checking VIGRANUMPY_DEPENDENCIES
-- Using Python 2.7.17 at /usr/bin/python
-- Found Python includes:  /usr/include/python2.7
-- Found Python library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
-- Could NOT find boost_python library (looking for version 2.7)
-- Searching for Python numpy: ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nose
-- Could NOT find Python nosetests ('import nose' failed)
-- Could NOT find sphinx documentation generator
-- Could NOT find VIGRANUMPY_DEPENDENCIES (missing: Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY) 
-- ** WARNING: test_classifier::RFHDF5Test() will not be executed
-- ** WARNING: test_hdf5impex will not be executed
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
-- VIGRA configuration information:
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
--   Using ZLIB  libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
--   Using PNG  libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
--   Using TIFF libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so
--   Using JPEG libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
--   OpenEXR disabled by user (WITH_OPENEXR=0)
--   Using FFTW libraries: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a
--   HDF5 libraries not found (HDF5 support disabled)
--   Using Boost Graph Library: /usr/include/boost/graph
--   LEMON graph library disabled by user (WITH_LEMON=0)
--   Vigranumpy dependencies not found (vigranumpy disabled)
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
--   building shared lib
--   binaries will be generated in: /home/elias/src/vigra/build
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
--   includes will be installed at: /usr/local/include
--   libraries will be installed at: /usr/local/lib
--   binaries will be installed at: /usr/local/bin
--   vigra manuals cannot be generated (Doxygen or Python not found)
--   vigranumpy will NOT be installed
-- 
-- Consider setting DEPENDENCY_SEARCH_PREFIX to find missing libraries
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/elias/src/vigra/build
```

Also, I have installed HDF5 libraries. Same here too.

I am trying to compile Hugin from source for using GPU. It requires VIGRA.

[I looked for info here](https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/912016cad95dc6d82cdb)

UPDATE 1:
I succeeded to install HDF5 dependencies... I am looking for the rest ones...

```
sudo cmake -DWITH_HDF5=1 -DDEPENDENCY_SEARCH_PREFIX=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

finally,

I found out that I must install lemon libraries (dev), openexr (dev) and HDF5 files.

`sudo apt-get install libopenxr-dev libhdf5-dev liblemon-dev`

and then compile vigra with

```
 sudo cmake -DWITH_HDF5=1 -DWITH_OPENEXR=1 -DWITH_LEMON=1 -DDEPENDENCY_SEARCH_PREFIX=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial[/usr/local]  ..
```